# Retornar um Result set de uma StoredProcedure MySql

Tags: mysql, delphi, stored-procedures

Tenho a seguinte *StoredProcedure* no *MySql*..:

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE DEFINER=`ricardo`@`%` PROCEDURE `teste2`()
BEGIN   
Select * from Tabela;    
END
```

Como eu chamo esta *StoredProcedure* pelo **DELPHI 7** ?
Estou usando os componentes ZEOS.
Já tentei com o ***zQuery..: Call teste2; open..exeqsql..*** não funcionou.
Já tentei com o ***ZStoredProc1..*** também não funcionou.. ele nem carrega na *propert* o nome da *StoredProcedure*.
Sei que poderia fazer um *sql* direto no componente, mas o descrito acima é só um exemplo.  A procedure executa várias operações e ao final existe um *sql* para ser retornado.
**Contudo**, mesmo no exemplo acima, um *sql* simples, não consegui retornar a *StoredProcedure* no Delphi para ser visualizada em uma grid.

Comment: Usar `Open();` em vez de `ExecSQL;` (usar `Query`)

Comment: Boa tarde @Sami . Como falei no post, já tentei usar tanto o open quanto o exeqsql com varias instruções diferentes dentro, mas sem sucesso.. De qualquer modo .. obrigado pela atenção :)

Comment: Você deve usar "Ativo"

Answer (score 0):

> Se o procedimento armazenado retornar um cursor a ser usado com controles de dados visuais, adicione um componente de fonte de dados ao módulo de dados e defina sua propriedade DataSet como o conjunto de dados do tipo de procedimento armazenado. Conecte componentes com reconhecimento de dados à fonte de dados usando suas propriedades DataSource e DataField.

You should use `"Active"` property of the `"StoredProcedure"`

```
ZStoredProc1.Prepare;
ZStoredProc1.Active:= True;
```

**[Referência](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_Stored_Procedure-type_Datasets)**

Comment: Hi. thank you for your attention. But this component don't have prepare methodh (for this verssion ) and the property active is the same that open and don't work